# Cythonizing specific methods of a class written in Python

Tags: python, c++, c, cython, cythonize

I have an A* planning algorithm written purely in Python (using this excellent [resource](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) on path planning). The grid class with associated methods for movement and costs is defined as follows:

```
class SquareGrid:
      def __init__(self, width, height):
          self.width = width
          self.height = height
          self.walls = []
          self.weights = []

      def in_bounds(self, id):
          (x, y) = id
          return 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height

      def passable(self, id):
          return id not in self.walls

      def neighbors(self, id):
          (x, y) = id
          results = [(x + 1, y), (x + 1, y - 1), (x, y - 1), (x - 1, y - 1), (x - 1, y), (x - 1, y + 1), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y + 1)]
          if (x + y) % 2 == 0: results.reverse()  # aesthetics

          results = [r for r in results if self.in_bounds(r)]
          results = [r for r in results if self.passable(r)] # this is where things slow down
          return results

      def cost(self, from_node, to_node):
          return (to_node[0] - from_node[0])**2 + (to_node[1] - from_node[1])**2
```

Now, I'd like to speed up execution a bit using Cython's static compiler goodness. One option would have been to rewrite the whole thing with static typing in Cython. I profiled the pure Python code using cProfiler to see where the bottleneck lies, and unsurprisingly enough, about 70% of the total execution time went into the `neighbors` method (which computes the valid neighboring nodes around the current node). More specifically, the list comprehension line in `neighbors` calls `passable` more than 33,000 times for a given toy example. `passable` checks if the node given in its argument is marked as "obstacle" or not by searching through `SquareGrid`'s knowledge of obstacles (`SquareGrid.walls`, a list of location tuples) and returns a boolean accordingly. It seemed to me that just by optimizing this particular method, I'd get significant gains in speed. So I set about rewriting `passable` in Cython.

I'm a complete noob at Cython and C/C++ in general, so I'd appreciate if any mistake in understanding how this thing actually works is pointed out. I created a pyrex file `passable_cy.pyx` with the hope that compiling it using Cython/GCC++ and then binding it to a `SquareGrid` object in the main script would be enough. This is how I defined `passable_cy.pyx`:

```
cpdef bint passable(object self, tuple id):
    return id not in self.walls
```

The accompanying `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name="cynthonized_passable", ext_modules=cythonize(['passable_cy.pyx']),)
```

And this is how I bound the new cynthonized method to `SquareGrid` in the main A* python script:

```
 g = SquareGrid(100, 100) # create grid with dimensions 100x100
 g.passable = types.MethodType(passable_cy.passable, g)
```

Everything compiled properly and the whole thing executed without problems. There was no speed improvement whatsoever, which I kind of expected (seemed too straightforward). How do I proceed from here? Is this method-binding thing the best way to go about it? I'm sure more can be done in `passable_cy.pyx`, but I'm too unfamiliar with C/C++ to know what to do.

Comment: Before bringing in Cython, you should consider making algorithmic improvements. `passable` is currently making a linear search through a list of all walls just to check whether its argument is a wall. Why not have SquareGrid store an *actual grid* of walls, so you can just look at the grid cell in O(1) and see whether there's a wall there?

Comment: Look-up in a build-in data structure isn’t something Cython could speed up. You could use a set instead of a list for ‘walls’ - the lookup would become O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: Using a set for `SquareGrid.walls` did speed up things massively, thanks! Although this does satisfy my performance requirements, do you think it's worth exploring the Cython option here? If so, a few pointers (heh) on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cython would be my last option, if I were sure everything else is optimal. Is passable still the bottleneck?

Comment: No, the passable bottleneck has been resolved. I'm fairly confident the pure Python code is as fast as it can get, barring a few minor alterations. I'm just curious if any more significant speed up can be achieved with Cython.

Comment: I doubt you'd get much more speed-up. You'd probably need to make moderately big changes for pretty little gain. If I had to do it I'd probably make `results` an `N` by `2` typed array and try to deal with typed numbers rather than tuples. I can't see how you'd realistically beat a quick `set` lookup though.

Comment: I get why people are telling you to avoid Cython here, but I can't get an answer to the overall question asked in this question: is it possible to cythonize just specific methods of a class? Does cython work with that?